# Catch and repsonse custom json on 405 HTTP error - ASP.NET CORE API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to capture error 405 to launch a personalized response, but I can not do it. When I make a call to the method, I get a generic error of CORS problem

```
//Startup.cs
servicesCollection.AddCors(x =>
{
    x.AddPolicy(CORS.AllowPutMethod,
        policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .WithMethods(HttpMethods.Put).AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    x.AddPolicy(CORS.AllowPostMethod,
        policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .WithMethods(HttpMethods.Post).AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

public static class CORS
{
    public const string AllowPutMethod = nameof(AllowPutMethod);

    public const string AllowPostMethod = nameof(AllowPostMethod);
}

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    // PUT: api/User/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [EnableCors(CORS.AllowPostMethod)] <=== ERROR HERE!!!
    public void Put(int id, UserDTO currentUser)
    {
    }

}
```

[image: HTTP ERROR (Angular 6)]

[image: Response]

Answer (score 1):

You shoul use `CORS.AllowPutMethod` instead of `CORS.AllowPostMethod` on the `Put` method.

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [EnableCors(CORS.AllowPutMethod)] 
    public void Put(int id, UserDTO currentUser)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Hello, that is on purpose as well to try to capture the error "405 Methos not allowed", but I can not do it.

Comment: For `Method not allowed` error, I think it is a CORS bug, and I have submitted it here [https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3327 ].